# Content Management System or Any other suggestions

Tags: html, web, content-management-system

I'm working on a website right now, and i'm wondering on how can my client edit the content of the website without looking at the html files cause they really don't know how to use those, or should i say, can they edit the content from the website's interface itself by just typing something that will enable admin control or something like that? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can code in php for a client's interface to add content to the website. It sis possible but have limited expansions in future.

OR

You can choose a CMS(preferably Wordpress) to achieve this. It has good user interface without any hassle and less codes. Easy to use too.